# Simulating desired throughput in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to achieve the throughput 7.6 requests per second.
I am using bzm- Concurrency Thread Group with Feedback function and Throughput shaping timer as below. Please ignore the thread groups which are striked out. They are disabled and are not executed by Jmeter.

[image]

[image]

When I run the script from command line, it shows the logs as below

[image]

And in the log file, it mentions that:

[image]

In the Concurrency Thread Group, I have defined Target Concurrency with a Feedback function as ${__tstFeedback(tst-name,1,100,30)}

Here, 1 and 100 are starting threads and max allowed threads, 30 is how many spare threads to keep in thread pool.

My first question is:

Q1. Why in the command line logs it says that no free threads are available in the current thread group. As you can see from the command line, only 39 threads started. I have defined max allowed threads as 100. On the top of that 30 are kept in the thread pool so that Jmeter can use them if 100 threads are not enough. I also tried increasing the number of threads by passing ${__tstFeedback(tst-name,1,200,30)} , but still I get the same error.

Still why does it say in the logs that no free threads available and hence increase your number of threads?

Also, as you can see from the Summary report, Transaction Controller for Scenario 3 and Scenario 4 are not executed by Jmeter

[image]

Q2. What could be the reason that Scenario 3 and Scenario 4 are not executed by Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

- `Q1` the warning is being written in 6 milliseconds after test start when only 1 thread was running, do you really expect that 1 thread can conduct the load of 7.6 requests per second? I mean theoretically it's possible, if your application response time is below 130 ms, however I don't think it's applicable for your case, try starting with i.e. 30 threads and remove these ramp-up period and steps.
- `Q2` we don't know, most probably the reason is that your test doesn't run long enough so first thread isn't able to execute all samplers in scenarios 1 and 2 or there are some [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) which prevent these scenarios execution or there is a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler which doesn't allow the thread to go further, etc.

The answers are always in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), you [might also want to increase the JMeter log level for the Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer" level="debug" />
```